# Is it possible to find records in a table by value in object (without providing a key)?

Tags: json, postgresql, indexing

I have a table `profile` which looks like:

```
id  | name (jsonb)                       | lots of different fields ...
1   | {en: "Some name", fr: "Un nom"}    | ...
2   | {ru: "Какое то название"}          | ...
```

Is it possible to find all records in a table with a value `Some name`?

I use Postgresql 12

Comment: I don't understand your problem. Perhaps it would be easier with some sample data and the expected result.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I simplified my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to unnest the json object:

```
select p.*
from profile p
where exists (select *
              from jsonb_each(p.name) as j(k,v)
              where j.v = 'Some name');
```

With Postgres 12 this can also be written using a [JSON path](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-SQLJSON-PATH) expression:

```
select p.*
from profile p
where name @? '$.keyvalue() ? (@.value == "Some name")'
```